# Wordpress don't save changes some times

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an `wordpress` website and have a lots of user's that write content in it. Sometimes when users edit or create new post and save it, after refresh it disappeared.

I have a backup system that `mysqldump` all database every 8. I don't know that this may cause the problem or not.

Comment: have you thought about replication instead of dumping the database?

Comment: Every 8 what? How are you taking the dump? What is the response of the request when it fails?

Comment: Probably better to ask this question here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I use borgbackup for my backups.